# Вывод ASCII-кода символа

Tags: c, сокет, ascii

С сокет-сервера я отправляю символ ASCII-код которого равен 65(A).

```
s.sendall(chr(65).encode("utf-8"))
```

Клиент написанный на Си, принимает этот символ.

```
char buf[10];
recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf) , 0);
```

Как мне на клиенте вывести ASCII код символа ?

Comment: `printf("%d", buf[0]);`

Comment: `chr(65).encode("utf-8")` это как минимум - избыточно.. печать: `printf("%c - 0x%x", buf[0], buf[0]);

Comment: @avp почему для символа 256 выводится -60 ?

Comment: Символ с кодом 256 в ASCII отсутствует. Символы ASCII имеют коды от 0 до 255.

Comment: @freim почему тогда символ 250 выводится как -61 ?

Comment: 250 при выводе как байт со знаком будет -6, а не -61. Если у вас не так, значит у вас в программе ошибка, и выводится какой-то мусор.

Comment: Надо использовать беззнаковый тип: `unsigned char a = (unsigned char)buf[0];` - это грубое и неточное приведение типа к значению, для простого примера.

Comment: @rootkit.sys, потому, что `char` знаковый тип (впрочем ascii-коды находятся в диапазоне 0-127 и будeт печататься как положительный). Если хотите, чтобы любой байт печатался как положительное число, просто приведите его тип к `unsigned char` -- `printf("%d", (unsigned char)buf[0]);`